# Iterating reversed on SplayTreeSet

Tags: dart

According to `Set` documentation:

> *LinkedHashSet* iterates in the insertion order of its elements, and 
>   a sorted set like *SplayTreeSet* iterates the elements in sorted
>   order.

So, if you want set functionality and you control the order of iteration, `SplayTreeSet` is the correct choice.

But how would you **efficiently** iterate over the set in reverse order (like STL `reverse_iterator`)?
In certain scenarios I want to go forward and in others I want the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now `splay.toList().reversed` seems the way to do that. You can perhaps [file an issue](http://dartbug.com/new) to add a `reversed` property on `SplayTreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to go backwards.

Having `reversed` on SplayTreeSet would make a kind of sense. It would be based on the same tree, but just swap the meaning of first/last and the iteration order.

Often creating the set with the reversed `Comparator` would be enough, but if you want to go both ways on the same map, or don't know the direction before creating the set, there is no simple solution.

Comment: "or there is no simple solution" - does this mean given the way it is implemented? Yes - in this case I want the same data in a set that in some cases I'll iterate forward, in others reverse. Maybe there is a better way, but suppose you have a sorted collection of accounts to fund activity and invest in. They are sorted such that when funding you should select accounts from the end to sell undesirables, but when investing you invest from the front to buy into most desirable based on sort criteria. The set functionality aids in removing accounts when balance drops to 0 or adding for reverse.

Comment: I can see the usefulness of reverse iteration. There are two ways to do that: either make the iterator a bi-directional iterator (which is rare and often not that useful), or make a reversed view of the collection, either just as an Iterable (so only iterating backwards) or as a Set that can be used as any other set, just backed by the original. There is nothing that inherently prevents either solution, it's "just" a matter of implementing it.